# C# - Xamarin - SQLite -CreatingTable

Tags: c#

I develop Xamarin app with SQLite. I do it according to tutorial but I am little confuse how creating table works.

(but this code work)

Here are two used classes.

```
 class DBwriter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public int Date { get; set; }

        public DBwriter(string name, string phone, int date)
        {
            Name = name;
            PhoneNumber = phone;
            Date = date;
        }

        public DBwriter()
        {

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " " + PhoneNumber;
        }
    }
```

And second class.

```
 class LiteDB
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbTest1.db3");
        public void DBconn()
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

            //setup a table
            db.CreateTable<DBwriter>();

            //create a new contact object
            DBwriter mycon = new DBwriter("Hello", "666-666-668", 5);
            //store the object into the table
            db.Insert(mycon);
            db.Close();

        }
```

I dont know whats happens in `db.CreateTable<DBwriter>();`

Means `<DBwriter>` to call constructor from class DBwriter and create columns name,phone and date according to arguments in constructor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CreateTable method will create the table based on the type if it doesn't exist.

```
//Create the database, only will be created if they don't exist;
db = new SQLiteConnection(path);

//Create the tables, only will be created if they don't already exist.
db.CreateTable<MyClass>();
```